# How to use combine with UiRepresentable?

Tags: swiftui

I have created a UiTextView in SwiftUi with the help of UiRepresentable. I would like to send a notification back to my SwiftUi when textViewDidEndEditing is called, so I can use it like this inside my SwiftUi code

```
SampleView
{
}
.onRecieve(Customview.isTextViewDidEndEditing)
{
// Update Code
}
```

is it possible to Conform my customView Class to ObservableObject make this work ?

Here is my Sample code for CustomTextView

```
struct CustomView : UIViewRepresentable

{
    @Binding var text : String


    let willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var textViewDoneEditing : Bool? {didSet {willChange.send()}}


    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {

        return Coordinator(self)
    }


    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate, ObservableObject

    {

    var parent: CustomView

           init(_ uiTextView: CustomView) {

               self.parent = uiTextView

           }

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

            parent.text = textView.text

        }


        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

            print("Ediiting is Done")


        }  

    }

   func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomView>) -> UITextView {


        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator

        return textView
    }


    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<CustomView>) {

        uiView.text = self.text

    }



}
```

Comment: Why don’t you use  SwiftUI’s native TextField?

Comment: I'll be interested in the answer. For me, I ended up **not** using `Combine` and simply using `Notification` - not exactly SwiftUI-like, but I found no other way. It also removed the need for an added "layer" of a representable and instead going straight from my `ObservableObject` into my `UIKit` object.

Comment: @LuLuGaGa I need multiline editing support, which TextField doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to make any SwiftUI View conform to `ObservableObject`. A simple binding property will do, as that will pass any relevant data back up the chain.

Further, Swift `struct` types cannot conform to `ObservableObject`, as per the protocol's declaration:

```
protocol ObservableObject : AnyObject
```

`AnyObject` is a `class`, or reference type. One would use something like `ObservableObject` to listen to a view model, or a data store, or the like. To pass data up the view chain from a SwiftUI view, use `@Binding` instead.

You would simply assign to the `text` binding when your new value comes in.

Then, from the calling view's `body`, you may instantiate your view, passing in a bindable property (such as `@State` using the `$` prefix, or a custom `Binding` property).

```
var body: some View {
    SampleView(text: $model.text)
}
```

SwiftUI handles the rest for you!

[Documentation on `ObservableObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/observableobject)

Comment: I know it's been a few weeks, so I hope you figured this out a while ago. (If not, that's okay, too!)